# Xabber android client: Resource line

Tags: android, xmpp

Potential scam check

Hello good people. I hava bit of a concern here so i have to ask.

I am doing a deal with someone on jabber and we're using a garantor/escrow but certain things doesn't add for me. Well, just 1.

I am using the Xabber android client.

When i tap on the person's contact info, it give me 3 line:

Client: psi+/pc
Resource: win-v33yl835sfp
Priority:40

And the "2nd" person?

Client: psi+/pc
Resource: win-v33yl835sfp
Priority: 50

Why does 2 supposedly different people have the same resource line? (The seller and the garantor)

Is this guy playing smart? Am i talking to same person on 2 different accounts? Pretending to be a garantor?

Am i paranoid?

That their would be 2 different Resource values seen that it's 2 different individuals